# Any clustering algorithms for points which are equidistant apart, holding different values?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have a data set with equidistant points with different values, like a 2D matrix, for example:

```
[[1, 2, 1, 5, 6]
 [2, 1, 4, 7, 6],
 [5, 1, 9, 3, 7]]
```

I want to do clustering based on the value, but with the points being spatially (equidistant) constrained. I plot this data in a colourmap, so perhaps to group the data based on values close to each other.

Are there any algorithms for this?

(Edited for clarity)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `skimage.slic` or a similar algorithm from the [example in skimage.segmentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_segmentations.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-segmentations-py)

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage import segmentation

a = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 5, 6],
 [2, 1, 4, 7, 6],
 [5, 1, 9, 3, 7]])

segments = segmentation.slic(a, n_segments=4)

print(segments)

>>> [[0 0 1 1 2]
     [0 0 1 1 2]
     [3 3 4 4 5]]
```

You can then adjust the **compactness** and **number of segments** to your need